# Local storage of google email in ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, local-storage, google-signin

```
user:ProfileModel

 export class ProfileModel {
 image: string;
 name: string;
 role: string;
 description: string;
 email: string;
 provider: string;
 phoneNumber: string;
 }

signInWithEmail() {
 this.authService
  .signInWithEmail(
    this.signInForm.value["email"],
    this.signInForm.value["password"]
  )
  .then((user) => {
    //to retrieve expenses from firebase for the email that is used upon signin 
    localStorage.setItem("email", this.signInForm.value["email"])
    // navigate to user profile
    this.redirectLoggedUserToProfilePage();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    this.submitError = error.message;
  });
}
```

this is the codes for sign in where local storage of email upon filling up signin form

```
googleSignIn() {
 this.authService
  .signInWithGoogle()
  .then((result: any) => {
    // localStorage.setItem('email', result.user.email);
    if (result.additionalUserInfo) {
      
      this.authService.setProviderAdditionalInfo(
        
        result.additionalUserInfo.profile
      );
    }
    ;
    this.redirectLoggedUserToProfilePage();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

this is the google sign in codes and i want to local storage the email but i tried this code

```
localStorage.setItem('email', result.user.email);
```

but is unable to local storage the email and unable to login as it refresh by itself.